# Ubuntu 23.10 asking for TPM recovery key on every boot after firmware update

Tags: uefi, 23.10, tpm

As the title says, I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 with the newly introduced TPM based FDE, i got a firmware update (for UEFI dbx) the other day so i did the update, then after reboot it asked me to enter TMP recovery keys, thankfully I made sure to backup them during installation so i was able to boot by entering it, but since then everytime i turn on my laptop it shows a message like this:

```
Please enter the recovery key for disk /dev/disk/by-partuuid/c7f7971b: (press TAB for no echo)
```

Again since I've my recovery key backed up, I'm able to boot, but it's getting very annoying to write the 40 words long recovery key everytime to turn on my laptop, shouldn't it save the recovery key when I first entered it after firmware upgrade? Is there anyway to save the key manually & fix this issue so i don't have to write the TPM recovery key on literary every boot?

Here's the image https://te.legra.ph/file/d7279dbe24979871cee2f.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution! Thanks to [jamesps on Ubuntu discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-23-10-asking-for-tpm-recovery-key-on-every-boot-after-firmware-update/40656/4?u=starry69)

Apparently updating the kernel refreshes the TPM binding and hence fixes this issue.

So now you got two options

1. Either wait for the new kernel update
2. Force it by switching to a new kernel snap channel by doing:

```
sudo snap refresh pc-kernel --channel=23.10/beta

## REBOOT

sudo snap refresh pc-kernel --channel=23.10/stable

## REBOOT
```