# Manually Binding TPM2 For FDE In Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: boot, luks, 23.10, tpm

In Ubuntu 23.10, you can use TPM2 to unlock LUKS; however, after a firmware update, the system asks for the recovery key in every boot. I was expecting it to refresh TPM2 after entering the key, just like BitLocker, but that's not the case.

A [possible solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494315/ubuntu-23-10-asking-for-tpm-recovery-key-on-every-boot-after-firmware-update) is to refresh pc-kernel or switch pc-kernel channel, but that didn't work for me.

My question is how to manually bind TPM2 instead of relying on `snap refresh pc-kernel` to do the job?

I have searched gnome-desktop-installer but found nothing; perhaps the related code is in the pc-kernel snap package? I just don't know where to find it.